# Is it possible to force cookie matching for Safari browser?

Tags: cookies, safari, ssp

We want to display ads on Safari using Lexicon (a solution provided by SSP 33across). Lexicon does not have "integration", it is a solution operating entirely on the SSP side. Lexicon works based on cookie matching. This is our only obligation. Lexicon works on Firefox, Edge, Opera - confirmed.

Problem - Cookie matching does not fire when using Safari.

Our success criteria are:

1. There is a page / endpoint that you can visit, which gives a very good chance of firing a matching cookie on Safari for 33across
2. The solution works on all browsers
3. Solution injects cookie of user's choice SSP (I can choose 33across, I can type Appnexus, etc.)

My initial research:

1. Use a third-party cookie management tool: Safari blocks third-party cookies by default, which may be preventing the cookie matching from occurring. Using a tool like CookiePro or OneTrust can help you manage cookies in a compliant way, and may help with cookie matching on Safari.
2. Implement a first-party cookie solution: If you have access to the website's code, you could implement a first-party cookie solution that would work with Lexicon. This would involve setting a first-party cookie on your domain that Lexicon could use for matching.
3. Test different cookie types: Lexicon may work with different types of cookies, such as localStorage or sessionStorage. You could test different cookie types to see if any of them work with Safari.

Are those initial thought worth considering? Is it feasible to achieve any of the goals using those proposals or maybe should we focus on something else? Especially the first goal is important, namely forcing Safari to cookie matching.